# How to update a column with INSERT ... ON CONFLICT only if the old value is NULL

Tags: postgresql, upsert

```
INSERT INTO main_parse_user ("user_id","group_id", "username", "bio", "first_name") 
VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5) 
ON CONFLICT (user_id) 
DO UPDATE 
SET ("group_id", "username", "bio", "first_name") = (EXCLUDED.group_id, EXCLUDED.username, EXCLUDED.bio,EXCLUDED.first_name)
```

Here is my code for adding and editing data to db at the same time

Now it works like this:

`user_id|group_id|@username|bio|first_name`

And if the database had a previously user_id, then it edits and adds data from the new request to the remaining fields

But I need to do it a little differently.

Let's say I have data in the database

`12345|-10015488|@abcd|None|Dev`

And I added a new line with exactly the same ID but with a change in bio

`12345|-10015488|@abcd|Developer|Dev`

And when I don’t have bio (`None`) on the old database, I need to add a new value to the database, and if there was information in bio initially, then the algorithm simply skips

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `coalesce`:

```
... DO UPDATE
   SET (bio, first_name) =
       (
           coalesce(main_parse_user.bio, EXCLUDED.bio),
           EXCLUDED.first_name
       )
```

It is necessary to qualify the original column value with the table name to disambiguate it from the new value

Comment: How can you combine this?
I want him to change bio if there is no value there, but if username, group_id, first_name (None or there are values) always changed

Comment: I spelled it out for the composite case now.

Comment: Can you check why it doesn't work for me?

Comment: Please don't write answers that are not answers. You did it different from the way I recommend in my answer. Look again!